# How to get badrequest message in JS code

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, message, bad-request

I can't find any solution, so I decided to ask this question. In my app when user tries to make more than 3 requests to rent a book I return in C# :

```
return BadRequest("Too many requests.");
```

In a browser concole I see that response was sent (status code 400) and a message is:

```
{message: "Too many requests."}
```

the thing is I can't figure out how to get this message in JS code in fail method.

```
.fail(function (respond) {
    alert(respond.message);
});
```

When I try: `alert(respond)` it shows: `[object Object]`

Do you have any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you check `alert(respond.message);`?

Comment: Do a `console.dir(respond)`, see what's inside that object. Also, you shouldn't return `400 Bad request`, you should return [`429 Too many requests`](https://httpstatuses.com/429) with an additional [`Retry-After: <delay-seconds>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) header. I mean if you care about standards and all that nonsense :)

Comment: I checked. Alert display:  undefined .

Comment: evilSnobu I have to clarify something. I wasn't precise enought.  User request is actually a Rental Request which admin can accept or reject. If user try to rent more than 3 books (3 new requests without admin reaction are in system) than I return 400 Bad request. Shoud I still change it for 429 or sth ?

Comment: evilSnobu I tried as you advised me - console.dir(respond). Thank you very much. I could clearly see that it is: respond.responseJSON.message .   And it works :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can get your bad request message with:

```
console.log(respond.responseJSON.Message);
```

or

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
console.log(obj.Message);
```

both are correct, but first example is better